# Prevent iPhone App from adapt to iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, splash-screen

i have an application which i built for an iPhone 5. When the iPhone 6 did not exist and that the app was not ready for iPhone 6 the app simply stretchs its contents so it looked good for me. 
Nevertheless to submit my app to the app store i need to add some splashcreens when i add the splascreens for iPhone 6 & 6+ the app adapt its content to the screen size, it is no more stretched.

I wonder if someone had a tip where i can add the missing splashscreen and keep my app unchanged so it will stretched to the screen.

Thanks

Comment: iPhone 5, 6 and 6+ have 16/9 screen. If you put a splash screen for iPhone 5, it'll be use by default for iPhone 6 and 6+. I think you should simply not put those iPhone 6/6+ splashscreen

Comment: Cannot submit the app without the splascreen ... but thanks

Comment: When do you receive the alert of the splashcreens?

Comment: when submitting to the App Store using Application Loader.

Comment: If splashscreen became mandatory it simply means that Apple want you to do the job you're trying to avoid ;)

Comment: :) just trying thanks.